# If else not working in Document Ready function

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am creating a page that selects a different form for running different functions when a user selects different select options.  What I am having trouble with is keeping the form displayed when I submit the form for my second function, even though the one for the first function works perfectly.  So that leads me to believe the problem is in my conditions in my document.ready function.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            <?php

                $function = $_POST['function'];
                if($function === 'nameFunc'){

                    echo "$('.funcDisplay').show();";
                    echo "$('.output').html('$output');"; 

                }

                else if($function === 'hamFunc'){

                    echo "$('#hFunc').show();";
                    echo "$('.output').html('$output');"; 

                }
            ?>

         });
```

This is where I feel like the problem lies.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {


        if($_POST['function']== 'nameFunc')
        {
            $fname = $_POST['fname'];
            $lname = $_POST['lname'];
            $output = "Hi $fname $lname, welcome to my PHP challenge";
        }

        if($_POST['function']== 'hamFunc') {

            $output = 3;

        }

    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bebk9hPHP.css">
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contentWrapper">
            <h1 id="header">PHP Sample Project</h1>
            <h3 id = "sText">Form Selection</h3>
            <div class="custom-select">
                <select id="dropdown">
                    <option selected disabled hidden>Select a function</option>
                    <option value="1">Function 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Function 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Function 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Function 4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="funcDisplay" id="funcDisp">
                    <h3>Name Function:</h3>
                   <form action="bebk9hPHP.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="fname" class="name" id="fieldOne" placeholder="First name...">
                        <input type="text" name="lname" class="name" id="fieldTwo" placeholder="Last name...">
                        <input type="text" name="function" value="nameFunc" class="hidField">

                        <div class="submits">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="clear nsubmit" name="submit">
                            <input type="button" value="Clear" class="clear nclear">
                       </div>
                    </form>
                <h2 class = "output"></h2>

            </div>
            <div class="hfuncDisplay" id="hFunc">
                    <h3>Hamming Number Function:</h3>
                <form action="bebk9hPHP.php" method="get">
                    <input type="text" name="hnum" class="hnum" placeholder="Enter Possible Hamming Number">
                    <input type="text" name="function" value="hamFunc" class="hidField">
                    <div class="submits">
                         <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="clear nsubmit" name="submit">
                         <input type="button" value="Clear" class="clear nclear">
                    </div>
                </form>
            <h2 class="output"></h2>




            </div>

        </div>


     <script>

        $("#hidField").hide();

        $(".funcDisplay").hide();
        $(".hfuncDisplay").hide();

         $("#dropdown").change(function(){

         if($("#dropdown :selected").val() == 1) {
                $(".funcDisplay").show();
                $(".hfuncDisplay").hide();
                $('.output').html("");
         }

         else if($("#dropdown :selected").val() == 2)  {
                $("#hFunc").show();
                $(".funcDisplay").hide();
                $('.output').html("");
         }
         })

         $(document).ready(function() {
            <?php

                $function = $_POST['function'];
                if($function === 'nameFunc'){

                    echo "$('.funcDisplay').show();";
                    echo "$('.output').html('$output');"; 

                }

                else if($function === 'hamFunc'){

                    echo "$('#hFunc').show();";
                    echo "$('.output').html('$output');"; 

                }
            ?>

         });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is all of my html.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have any errors at your console?

Comment: No errors.  Very confused as the logic seems sounds. @FabioAssunaco

Comment: You have this part here echo "$('.output').html('$output');" if $output is a php variable you should concatenate it like echo "$('.output').html('".$output."');"

Comment: All of your jQuery should be in `.ready(function(){ /* in here */)`. PHP executes on the Server before the web page is sent to the Browser. It doesn't execute inside JavaScript dynamically, if that is what you are thinking. Use AJAX.

Comment: Anything besides the single quotes around that variable breaks the page. @FabioAssuncao

Comment: What do you mean? I'm just using the document.ready so when the page is submitted and the page gets refreshed the correct form is still on screen. @StackSlave

Comment: That's not what it's for. It's so jQuery is ready. Use AJAX.

Comment: Haven't learned AJAX yet, you don't think I can get it to work for both with my current implementation? It works perfectly for the first one.  Just trying to get this assignment done I appreciate your help.  @stackslave

Comment: According to your question, I'm not sure you need to use the Server at all for this, I just assumed you had to since you're code shows PHP. Just use the jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Move all of this into your document ready function before anything else runs in it:

```
        $("#hidField").hide();

        $(".funcDisplay").hide();
        $(".hfuncDisplay").hide();

         $("#dropdown").change(function(){

         if($("#dropdown :selected").val() == 1) {
                $(".funcDisplay").show();
                $(".hfuncDisplay").hide();
                $('.output').html("");
         }

         else if($("#dropdown :selected").val() == 2)  {
                $("#hFunc").show();
                $(".funcDisplay").hide();
                $('.output').html("");
         }
         })
```

You declare `hidField` as a CSS class yet refer to in the jQuery selector as a CSS id. Correct this:

```
$("#hidField").hide();
```

to

```
$(".hidField").hide();
```

Carefully go thru your code to weed out any other mistakes. Consider renaming your identifiers to something that indicates more clearly as to what type of DOM elements they are. This will help you debug better.